# Why is this question still considered unclear?

Tags: discussion, specific-question, closed-questions, reopen-closed

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41543428/finding-the-largest-possible-number-in-permutations-of-digits-less-than-a-limit) question has been put on hold as unclear. This was perfectly fine as the question was very unclear. I worked with the OP in a chat on what he wanted to ask and we ended up with a complete re-write of his question. All edits were approved but still the question is on hold. Unfortunately, I do not have the rep. to see the reopen votes or reviews, so I do not see why it is still on hold. Can anybody help here?
I think I have an answer to the question but I would prefer to post it as answer rather than writing it into the chat.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It has received 2 re-open votes, out of a required 5. So…why is it still "on hold"? Because you only made the edit an hour or so ago, and it hasn't yet received enough attention to be re-opened. (There are *a lot* of questions waiting to be re-opened after having been edited!)

If you were patient, it likely would have been re-opened.

After bringing it to Meta, *something* will happen even faster, but no guarantees on what that will be.
**Update:** The question was re-opened and appears to have survived the Meta effect relatively unscathed!

Comment: Ah ok, I thought reopening would happen at the same time as approving the edits. As the edits were approved, I assumed the reopen to be rejected. Thanks.

Comment: No, they are separate processes. Edits are much easier to get approved, and many edits do not have anything to do with closing or re-opening.